# Scan comments to get Links

Tags: php, jquery

I build my application using Zend-framework and Jquery, in the application there is Articles and Comments, users can put links in the comments, My question is how I can "Scan" posted comments and get posted Links to suggest them  to other users? do I need some PHP-regex or a Jquery plugin?
My Comments and Articles are stored in the DB, (I think SO use same system). 
Thanks.

Comment: In the absence of your code or other specific details, the best answer we can give is "maybe."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP's [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) and it's [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) method.

Don't use regular expressions since they aren't a good fit for parsing HTML.

Comment: There too few details in the original post to support this. If the comments are stored in a database, it wouldn't make much sense to generate a document for DOMDocument to consume when a query will work just as well.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @GeorgeCummins What I get from the question is that he'd like to extract the links and (what I assume) store them somewhere else for faster indexing so he can easily suggest them to other users. I don't really see how a query would be beneficial in this case.